# How to get auth token REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I followed the instruction on page https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs
[image]

The result I got is slightly different to what's said in the document.
[image]
It doesn't provide something like AUTH_tkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Did I do anything incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by getting the token from returned header.